# How to add mutliple columns against row in DatagridView c# Windows Application

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am creating one inventory system. 
I have a windows form with controls on that like 
Order No(`TextBox`), Cust Id(`Textbox`), Cust Name(`Textbox`), Product(`ComboBox`), Price(`Textbox`), Total(`Textbox`), ADD(`Button`), `DatagridView`.

So I would like to store data in gridview as

```
  Order No    Cust No    Cust Name   Product   Price   Total
         1         1         ABC       Laptop    35000  
                                       Printer    5000
                                       HDD        3500
                                       RAM        1200   44700
         2         2         XYZ       Keyboard    199
                                       PD          200      399
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit the DataGridView in designer, and add the columns to it's "Columns" collection. Then add a new click action to your "ADD" button:

```
private void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   dataGridView.Rows.Add(orderNo_TextBox.Text,
                         custID_Textbox.Text,
                         custName_Textbox.Text,
                         product_ComboBox.Text,
                         price_Textbox.Text,
                         total_Textbox.Text);

   dataGridView.Invalidate();
}
```

Replace the control names with the real ones.